# Propagate changes from child to parent scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm passing an object using an attribute from a parent scope to a child scope and I would like that changes made in the child scope are propagated to the parent scope.

Basically this is the parent view:

```
<foo oo-bar="object"></foo>
```

And this is `foo` directive:

```
angular.module('foo').directive('foo', function()
{
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : ConfigService.path.views + '/table/projects.html',
        scope : {
            bar : '=ooBar'
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the changes made in the parent scope are propagated to the child scope but not the other way around.

For example, if I try to `$scope.bar = 4` in the child scope, the parent's `bar` won't change.

What I understood is that Angular is creating a new `bar` in the child scope that's not linked with the `bar` in the parent's scope.

If that's the case, how can I propagate the changes back to the parent scope?

I thought that I could use a callback function, but I'm not sure that's the best way.

Edit: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5tnyOYgEAgOOaxIbyGzX?p=preview)

Comment: Do you have any fiddle/plunker for this?

Comment: How about using a service to solve this?

Comment: @VinayK I just added a plunker example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I was looking for I located here: [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

The key part is the following:

> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with ng-switch.
>
> Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use 
>   `<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1">` rather than 
>   `<input type="text" ng-model="prop1">`.
>
> If you really want/need to use a primitive, there are two workarounds:
>
> 1. Use `$parent.parentScopeProperty` in the child scope. This will prevent the child scope from creating its own property.
> 2. Define a function on the parent scope, and call it from the child, passing the primitive value up to the parent (not always possible)

Comment: It's called isolated scope for a reason. In `Child bar: {{ foo }}` `foo` is **not** in the isolated scope, but in the scope of `parentCtrl`.

Answer (score 1):

In parent scope you should have an object not primitve value, in that case changing object property in child scope will update also in parent . let me bring fiddle

```
$scope.object = {};
$scope.bar = '' // wrong way its a primiive
```

[Demo without object](http://plnkr.co/edit/CPxLfOFfE71pCvG8lPdz?p=preview)

[Demo with object](http://plnkr.co/edit/9wMDDlPl4b95pX4qwe0n?p=preview)

Comment: There is no child scope in the OP's example. `foo` is in the same scope as `bar`.

Comment: THANK YOU. "should have an object not primitive value" was the piece of info that helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

```
<parent ng-controller="parentCtrl">
  Parent bar: {{ bar }}
  <child foo="bar">
    Child bar: {{ foo }}
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo">
  </child>
</parent>
```

All the elements inside `parent` node will be compiled with the scope of  `parentCtrl`.

`{{ bar }}` -- `{{ foo }}` will be evaluated with the scope of `parentCtrl`.

Initially there is no `foo` defined in the `parentCtrl`, hence it did not print any value.

As you type in the input field, `ng-model` will create a variable `foo` in the scope with which it (`ng-model`) is compiled (i.e, parentCtrl) and update it.

Now we have `foo` in the parentCtrl's scope.

As `{{ foo }}` is compiled with the scope of parentCtrl, it will display the value that is entered in the textbox.

**Two-Way binding**

```
scope : {
   foo: '='
}
```

this will create a two way binding between the parentCtrl scope `bar` and childCtrl scope `foo` variables.

If you change the value of foo in the link function of child directive. It will update the bar value in the parentCtrl scope.